# How to Make UITableview cells and UIButton's shape with new shape other than rect

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Is that possible to change the shape of the cells..
That means any polygon shape other than rectangle, round rectangle.
and also UIButton's shape

Answer (score 0):

Create a table view with `UITableViewStylePlain`.
After this use:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Then subclass the `UITableViewCell` class and in the `drawRect:` method you can draw any shape you would like to.

Answer (score 0):

Views in iOS (including table cells) are always rectangular. So what you need to do is:

- Create a custom `UITableViewCell` (there are lots of examples and tutorials).
- When calculating the cell size, you need to calculate the bounding box of your shape. For example, if you want to draw a circle with radius `r`, you return a height of `r * 2`.
- Set `[UIColor clearColor]` as background color.
- In the `drawRect:` method, draw your shape.